# Simple js replace and return text?

Tags: javascript

This is probably simple, I want to replace the `_` (underscore) with nothing (space) and return the text. Take a look at my attempt.. http://jsfiddle.net/NcG78/

here is the code from the fiddle:

```
function formatNice(text) {
    $(function() {
        var new = text.replace('_', ' ');

        return new;
    });
}​
```

Comment: **NO** ***NO*** BAD DOG!

Comment: `new` is a keyword, don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: You're replacing the `_` character with a space; which is not 'nothing'. And here's a list of [JavaScript's 'reserved words'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) (that you shouldn't use for variable, or function, names (or anything else).

Comment: Some people are new at JavaScript. StackOverflow doesn't exclude amateurs and 'new' doesn't fit any other language paradigm that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove the non-needed jQuery!**

There is no need for it....

Just do:

```
function formatNice(text) {
   var newt = text.replace('_', ''); //can't use `new` as a variable name.
                                     //it is a "reserved word"
   return newt;
}​
```

Comment: Ok, but the document still isnt displaying the newly formatted text, I want to 'echo' it. Doesnt return do that?

Comment: You can `console.log` it. `document.write` it. `return` just returns from the function. You might want to read up on what a `function` is.

Comment: @JonahKatz return "returns" the value from the function. write `document.write(formatNice("your_text"))`

Comment: see [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585134/simple-js-replace-and-return-text#comment15330133_11585155)